# 3Ware 9500-4lp - Single Disk to RAID 1 - Possible?

Tags: raid, mirroring

I have a single disk attached to a 3Ware 9500-4LP controller. The unit is configured as Single Disk.
I have attached 2 more drives, identical size. Can I pair the 3 drives in a RAID 1 config, without destroying data in the single unit? That is, current Single Disk, should be used as the reference to start with.

Thank you

Comment: Possibly this should be achieved through 3bm2 interface

Comment: It is not a JBOD unit

Comment: @Riccardo The answers on that question still address this one ("If there are specific instructions provided by 3Ware you can try them (and it looks like you can do this with a Single Disk unit), but make sure you have good backups. You're probably better off making a backup, creating the RAID-1, and restoring.")

Answer (score 1):

- RAID1 is a mirror which requires pairs of disks not 3.
- there is no clone option in the bios, creating an array will wipe the existing
  data, you need to backup and restore.
- You may be able to migrate with 3dm2 although the documentation is conflicted

Handily you have 3 drives so you can create the array on the 2 other drives, use disk partitioning software to copy the data across, and then remove the original drive from the system.

Comment: Thank you James. Once done, I could maybe use the 3 drive as a hot spare...

Comment: Please close/delete this question, as it looks like the highlighted topic, partially answers my question. Thank you

Comment: Sorry if I ask to reopen the question: reading through the user guide it is explained that it is possible to achieve what I was looking for, however the operation has to be performed through 3Dm2. So the answer to the question is: yes!

Comment: My 3dm2 manual talks about cloning but only when you have 1 disk of a raid1.  If you just have a single disk then there is no rebuild option when you get to that point in the instructions.  They call the process you want to do migration.

Comment: I could successfully migrate the Single Drive to RAID 1 through 3DM2! Can someone here add the answer?

Comment: good job, it does mention that in the duplicate question so i'll amend my answer